# Only first link of Pagination working in Custom Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to integrate Pagination functionality into my Wordpress Custom Plugin. This plugin fetches the input and displays the results via Ajax.

When the results row are more than 7, I am using pagination. In this case, numeric link "1" is showing correct data whereas the rest of link it redirects to the [Admin Ajax Link](http://accessrealtytampa.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php/page/2/).

How can I make rest of the link make it work?

```
global $wpdb;
    $data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `wp_gj73yj2g8h_hills_school_data` " . $where_query_text  . ";"));
    $rows_per_page = 7;
    $current = (intval(get_query_var('paged'))) ? intval(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;


    $data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `wp_gj73yj2g8h_hills_school_data` " . $where_query_text  . ";"));

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $pagination_args = array(
    'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
    'format' => '',
    'total' => ceil(sizeof($data)/$rows_per_page),
    'current' => $current,
    'show_all' => false,
    'type' => 'plain',   
    );



if( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
 $pagination_args['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg('s',get_pagenum_link(1) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged');

if( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) )
 $pagination_args['add_args'] = array('s'=>get_query_var('s'));

    $output_string = '';

    $output_string .= paginate_links($pagination_args);

    $start = ($current - 1) * $rows_per_page;
    $end = $start + $rows_per_page;
    $end = (sizeof($data) < $end) ? sizeof($data) : $end;

    $output_string .= '<br>';

    $output_string .= '<div class="clearfix row">';
    $output_string .= '<div class="columns small-12 large-12">';
    $output_string .= '<h2 class="school-heading"><em>Schools</em></h2>';
    $output_string .= '<div class="horizontalLine"></div>';
    $output_string .= '</div>';
    $output_string .= '</div>'; 
    for($i=$start;$i < $end; ++$i)
    {
        $rows = $data[$i];
        /*Displays the Content*/            
    }
```

Comment: Why you are overriding `base` in `$pagination_args` ??  What happens if you remove this `$pagination_args['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg('s',get_pagenum_link(1) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged');`??

Comment: if I remove the particular line, it gets redirected to the http://accessrealtytampa.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?paged=2 and shows 0 on the screen

Comment: ok .. and where should it redirect? What is the desired output? I.E the links are wrong or the placeholder??

Comment: Link to my plugin is http://accessrealtytampa.com/hillsborough-county-homes-school/ Please select the value Tampa under City Dropdown in order to see results in Pagination.

Comment: I want to display results under this link

Comment: Have modified your code, can you please try this code .. https://codepaste.net/hv1ndt

Comment: After pasting the code only the change is it shows the website header and footer and it redirects to the http://accessrealtytampa.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php&paged=17 only giving a Page not found error